# Join after aggregate

Tags: rapidminer

I'm trying to make a join of two datasets and one of them has been aggregated. Both datasets have an id defined. 
I get the next error "Process failed: input example set does not have an id attribute"

What I'm doing wrong?
Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After aggregation, ids will disappear. You have to explicitly set a new one using the `Set Role` operator.